# Send more data in fcbkcomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fcbkcomplete

i have this question, i want to send a data like ajax but in fcbkcomplete.

Example:

in ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sys_pacientes/find_ciudades',
        data : {
            tag: $('#tag').val(),
            Anothertag: $('#tag').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

In fcbkcomplete i cant send more data than i already send, that data is (tag and _=1516258)this is a random number that the function send).

I want to send that data when i type and ajax send a request for search what i type.

Answer (score 0):

My friend to send a new data i have to add this in to the jquery.fcbkcomplete.js:

line: 477

$.getJSON(options.json_url, {"tag": xssDisplay(etext),"newData": $('#dataSelected').val()}, function(data) {

Where "newData" is the new element i send via ajax to getpost in php.